# decent performance profiler windows phone 7

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, profiling

I am looking for a performance/cpu profiler for Windows Phone 7 silverlight apps. Something like dotTrace or Ants Profiler. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend you use the Windows Phone SDK's profiler [(info on MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202934%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for profiling WP7.5 apps (it doesn't work with WP7.0 apps).

Answer (score 5):

You could try the [Eqatec profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/Home.aspx). It´s a code profiler that really shows you how much time you spent in each method call. It helped me a lot when analyzing my Windows Phone 7 app.
The free version can only profile one assembly, but it´s enough to get you started.